# BeautifulSoup doesn't find correctly parsed elements

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, html5lib

I am using `BeautifulSoup` to parse a bunch of possibly very dirty `HTML` documents. I stumbled upon a very bizarre thing.

The HTML comes from this page: http://www.wvdnr.gov/

It contains multiple errors, like multiple `<html></html>`, `<title>` outside the `<head>`, etc...

However, html5lib usually works well even in these cases. In fact, when I do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(document, "html5lib")
```

and I pretti-print `soup`, I see the following output: http://pastebin.com/8BKapx88

which contains a lot of `<a>` tags.

However, when I do `soup.find_all("a")` I get an empty list. With `lxml` I get the same.

So: has anybody stumbled on this problem before? What is going on? How do I get the links that `html5lib` found but isn't returning with `find_all`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to parsing a not well-formed and tricky HTML, [the parser choice](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) is very important:

> There are also differences between HTML parsers. If you give Beautiful
>   Soup a perfectly-formed HTML document, these differences won’t matter.
>   One parser will be faster than another, but they’ll all give you a
>   data structure that looks exactly like the original HTML document.
>
> But if the document is not perfectly-formed, different parsers will
>   give different results.

`html.parser` worked for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

document = requests.get('http://www.wvdnr.gov/').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(document, "html.parser")
print soup.find_all('a')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> document = requests.get('http://www.wvdnr.gov/').content
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(document, "html5lib")
>>> len(soup.find_all('a'))
0
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(document, "lxml")
>>> len(soup.find_all('a'))
0
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(document, "html.parser")
>>> len(soup.find_all('a'))
147
```

See also:

- [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

Comment: Very interesting. I was assuming html5lib and lxml were better than html.parser. Oh well, now I know better. Thanks!

Comment: html5lib should match what the HTML spec does and what web browsers do. If it doesn't, something is wrong.

Comment: Hmm — html5lib seems to find 147 `a` elements on its own, yet within BeautifulSoup is finding none. That seems like something is wrong on the BeautifulSoup side rather than html5lib.

Comment: I've reported this bug in BS4 [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1450884), FWIW.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the correct answer is "use another parser" (thanks @alecxe), I have another workaround. For some reason, this works too:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(document, "html5lib")
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.prettify(), "html5lib")
print soup.find_all('a')
```

which returns the same link list of:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(document, "html.parser")
```