# Python BeautifulSoup findAll not returning all the elements?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull data from this url https://99airdrops.com/page/1/.

The code I have written is below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_str = 'https://99airdrops.com/page/1/'

page = requests.get(url_str, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla Firefox'})

# soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# print(soup.prettify())

print(len(soup.findAll('div')))

print(soup.find('div', class_='title'))
```

My issue is the line `print(len(soup.findAll('div')))` is only returning 23, and the line `print(soup.find('div', class_='title'))` prints `None`. The find command isn't finding the div element with `class_='title'` even though there are multiple instances, and the div element is nested deeply in the html page but this has never caused me issues before.

I've tried using the `lxml` and `html.parser`, but neither is returning all the div elements. I also tried writing the html to a file, reading it in, and then running BeautifulSoup with it but I got the same results. Could someone tell me what the issue is here?

I also tried the suggestions here [Beautiful Soup - `findAll` not capturing all tags in SVG (`ElementTree` does)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016981/beautiful-soup-findall-not-capturing-all-tags-in-svg-elementtree-does) to update my lxml package but I run into the same issue still.

I also tried the solutions here [BeautifulSoup doesn't find correctly parsed elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896558/beautifulsoup-doesnt-find-correctly-parsed-elements) with no luck.

Comment: What data specifically are you trying to grab?

Comment: The title, prices, and dates for each entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can get all of the data you are looking for with a single request.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://cdn.99airdrops.com/static/airdrops.json')
>>> data = r.json()
>>> len(data)
133
```

For example:

```
>>> import json; print(json.dumps(data.popitem(), indent=2))
[
  "pointium",
  {
    "unique": "pointium",
    "name": "Pointium",
    "currency": "PNT",
    "description": "Global Decentralized Platform for Point Management & Loyalty Program",
    "instructions": "<ol><li>Join Telegram <a href=\"https://t.me/pointium\" target=\"_blank\">@Pointium</a> and click \"Join Airdrop\" (+500 PNT) </li><li>Enter your e-mail (+200 PNT) </li><li><a href=\"https://twitter.com/POINTIUM_ICO\" target=\"_blank\">Follow Twitter</a> and submit your username (+500 PNT) </li><li>Confirm your details</li></ol>",
    "rating": "7.30",
    "addDate": "2018-04-20 06:23:03",
    "expirationDate": "2018-05-07",
    "startDate": "2018-04-07",
    "image": "https://cdn.99airdrops.com/static/pointium.jpeg",
    "joinLink": "https://www.pointium.org/airdrop",
    "sponsored": "0",
    "status": "0",
    "startDateFormatted": "7th of April",
    "expirationDateFormatted": "7th of May",
    "attributes": {
      "bitcointalk": "0",
      "category": "airdrop",
      "email": "1",
      "facebook": "0",
      "kyc": "0",
      "news": "https://twitter.com/POINTIUM_ICO",
      "opinion": "O parere personala este ca merge acest sistem foarte bine. Doar ca mai avem de lucrat la el sa fie bomba!",
      "other": "0",
      "phone": "0",
      "ratingConcept": "7",
      "ratingTeam": "5.5",
      "ratingWebsite": "7",
      "ratingWhitepaper": "8",
      "reddit": "0",
      "telegram": "1",
      "tokenGiven": "1200",
      "tokenPrice": "0.007",
      "tokenSupply": "1,600,000,000",
      "tokenType": "ERC20",
      "twitter": "1",
      "website": "www.pointium.org"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This is great. I didn't know they had a json webpage.

Comment: @AlexF I just opened up chrome dev tools (F12), went to the network tab, reloaded the page and then looked at the requests being sent.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I followed your steps and was able to find it myself as well. I'll keep this tool in my head for next time.